# Fastest way to move code block to specific line

Tags: copy-paste, editing, yank

Say you have code on lines 4, 5, 6. Then you want to move this block of code to starting point line 9 while also deleting lines 4, 5, 6.

What's the fastest way, i.e. least amount of key strokes, to achieve this? Would a custom function be better suited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting at the beginning of line 4 (`ESC 4 ESC g g` or `M-4 M-g M-g` to go there), `C-3 C-k C-2 C-n C-y` (or `ESC 3 C-k down down C-y` if you don't like holding modifiers down) will do this.

If you don't want to do the arithmetic in your head, but instead select lines visually, then

- Move to the beginning of the zone to move
- `C-SPC` to set the mark
- Move down to the beginning of the first line to keep
- `C-w` to cut
- Move down to the place where you want to insert the cut text
- `C-y` to paste

I don't think there's any way to make this shorter unless you're willing to lose some flexibility (for example, if you often want to move a block of exactly three lines). You need to provide three locations: the beginning of the block to move, the end of the block to move, and the destination. In the sequences above, there is a single keystroke at each location, which is as low as it gets.

Answer (score 8):

If the distance not big you can use [move-text](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/move-text.el):

[image]

In terms of key strokes, for me it is:

1. Select region:

   <kbd>C-SPC</kbd><kbd>C-n</kbd><kbd>C-n</kbd><kbd>C-n</kbd>
2. Move region:

   <kbd>H-S-n</kbd><kbd>H-S-n</kbd><kbd>H-S-n</kbd>

(`move-text-down` is binded to <kbd>H-S-n</kbd>)

Comment: You can also provide a numeric argument `n` to `move-text-down` and `move-text-up`. This shortens step (2) to `M-3` `H-S-n`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) to mark the block, if it is a semantic unit, like a function (The package's website explains this in more detail). Then moving it around as the other response explains. Depending on where you are in the block, a single keystroke can mark the whole thing.

Comment: Can you expand on this? What do you mean a real block? Like a function block?

Comment: Yes, the term used in the package is "semantic units" which can be word, line, code block, function, class, whole file. I've edited the answer to include a link to the package that explains this better.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `evil-mode`, you can alternatively use an `ex` command: `:4,6m9` (which `m`oves lines `4` to `6` to line `9`).

Comment: I don't get the point of mentioning an exotic feature like vi emulation when it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Gilles: `evil-mode` isn't exactly obscure--it has almost 18,000 downloads on melpa. Another answer used `expand-region`, which is also an external package. For a Q&A site, it's probably good to include multiple ways to accomplish the same thing with different packages (although it might be good to come up with some guidelines).